# Lightning Events

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-events

Good day! Today I was tasked to do a simple "app/function" that will increment an integer from parent using a button from a child component. I understood how the code works but something just bothers me, how is that the `<aura:registerEvent name = "toEvent" type = "c:IncrementEvent"/>` from child component must be the same with `<aura:handler name="toEvent" event="c.IncrementEvent" action="{!c.getFromChild}"/>` from the parent controller?

Here is the rest of the code:

Parent.cmp

```
<aura:component >
<h1>Parent</h1>    
<aura:attribute name = "incremented" type = "Integer" default = "0"/>
<aura:handler name="toEvent" event="c.IncrementEvent" action="
{!c.getFromChild}"/>
<ui:outputText value = "{!v.incremented}"/>
<c:Child numFromParent = "{!v.incremented}"/>
</aura:component>
```

ParentController.js

```
({
getFromChild : function(component, event, helper) {

    var disp = event.getParam("pass");
    component.set("v.incremented", disp);
}
})
```

Child.cmp

```
<aura:component >
<aura:attribute name = "numFromParent" type = "Integer"/>
<aura:registerEvent name = "toEvent" type = "c:IncrementEvent"/>
<ui:button label="Click Here"
           press="{!c.increment}"/>
</aura:component>
```

ChildController.js

```
({
increment : function(component, event, helper) {
    var inc = component.get("v.numFromParent");
    inc++;

    var childEvent = component.getEvent("toEvent");
    childEvent.setParams({"pass": inc});
    childEvent.fire();
}
})
```

and finally the event IncrementEvent.evt

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT">
<aura:attribute name="pass" type="Integer" />
</aura:event>
```

Thanks in advance and more power guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understood your question (sorry if not) but the event `name` and `type`/`event` attributes must match between the `aura:registerEvent` and `aura:handler`.

Here is a [sample gist](https://gist.github.com/pozil/70e101ae3e22dc4330474ea2ffb040bb) showing all of the code required to fire and handle a Component Event.

You can find more information on events in the [Lightning Inter-Component Communication Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/04/lightning-inter-component-communication-patterns.html) blog post.

Cheers,

Comment: Hmm I see that they must much and that's what I am wondering. So.. register event and handler "MUST" always have a matching name?

Comment: Yes, it is mandatory.

Comment: @Cedirck does this answer your question? If so, please mark it as answered.

Comment: Oh sorry i am sure i clicked the check already to mark as answered guess my connection was acting up back then. Thanks @POZ